# Setting up the Imgur API: Error status 400 when Generating the Access Token at step 5 of documentation

Tags: imgur

I am following the documentation for getting started with the [Imgur API](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest).
I have followed all steps exactly, using the urls provided in the documentation where required.
I received the refresh token, copy/pasted it into 'Manage Environments' and filled the information out as specified using my Client Id and Secret (copy pasted directly from my imgur account). See below

[image: The Manage Environments interface]

At step 5 it says to run the Generate Access Token endpoint which I assume means press Send (*?*) But when I do this, the response is an error citing "The client credentials are invalid".
I have started again 3 times from step 1 of the documentation to make sure the values I'm providing are correct but I run into this error every time. Guys what am I doing wrong?!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to select the environment you just created, at the top-right.